Inconsistent float ABI when compiling for the RISC-V platform with flang-new
I am cross-compiling the SPEC CPU2006 benchmarks using the LLVM 19.1.0 compiler on an Intel machine. The C/C++ examples can be successfully built into executable files using runspec and run successfully on the** RISC-V** platform. However, for Fortran examples like 410.bwaves, building with flang-new fails, and the error is:
ld.lld: error: bwaves.lto.o: cannot link object files with different floating-point ABI from ~/gnu-riscv64-20241106/sysroot/usr/lib/crt1.o.
PS. config info
**FOPTIMIZE **= -march=rv64gcv_zba_zbb_zbc_zbs -O3 -static -flto -ffast-math
**EXTRA_LDFLAGS **= -fuse-ld==ld.lld -L${gnu-riscv64}/lib/
Through debugging, I found that the ABI of bwaves.lto.o is rv64i2p1, while the ABI of the library file crt1.o is rv64i2p1_m2p0_a2p1_f2p2_d2p2_c2p0_zicsr2p0_zmmul1p0. Clearly, bwaves.lto.o is generated incorrectly. Could you please advise me on how to resolve this issue? Thank you very much!
I tried to write a script to build the 410.bwaves example by first compiling each Fortran file into .bc files, and then linking those .bc files into an object file using flang-new. The ABI of this object file is correct, and flang-new can generate the executable file. However, to ensure accuracy, I need to execute the SPEC tests via the command line. Therefore, I would like to ask everyone where I might have gone wrong. Thank you very much!

Welcome, I sugggest to take the [tour] and read [ask] and [mcve]. Which exact compiler and linker commands are you running (or the script is running for you?

@VladimirFГероямслава FWIW I promoted this from staging ground.  I thought it looked like the material provided was enough to make a start at answering.  Apologies if it's still too vague and should have been brushed up there.

@Craig Those who know the details of the test suite might be able to reproduce the problem, maybe on a virtual machine, but I fear it is a long shot here among the fortran tag regulars. And I am not sure if other experts will look at it or even find it, given the Fortran topic. LLVM and FP ABI experts would be the best.
